# Extremely Simple PHP Form Not Working

Tags: php, forms

Hello I am trying to run an extremely simple php code involving forms. The code is not working at all, and I cannot figure out why. I want one message to display if nothing has been submitted and a different message to display if something has. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){$submit=$_POST['submit'];}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){$YesNo = $_POST['YesNo'];}

if(!isset($submit)){
 $message='<formname="radioTest"action="radiobuttontest.php?method="post"> ';
$message .='<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1"/>';
$message .="CLICK ONE OF THE RADIO BUTTONS";    
$message .=" \n <br />";
$message .=" \n <br />";
$message .="YES:";
$message .='<tr><input type="radio"name="YesNo"value="YES"/></tr>';
$message .='NO:';
$message .='<tr><input type="radio" name="YesNo"value="NO"/></tr>';
$message .='<tr><input name="go"type="submit"value="go" /></tr>';
$message .='</form>';
}
else{
$message = '"'.$YesNo.'"';
unset($submit);
unset($YesNo);
}

echo $message;
unset($message);
?>
```

Comment: Define "not working".  What *is* it doing?  Are there errors?  Unexpected behavior?  What's in the PHP logs?

Comment: @Dagon it's like saving on gas. *Econo-forms*.

Comment: sidenote: form does not bear the name attribute

Answer (score -1):

Make your form like this, you have to separate attributes of the tag and keep correct quotes (use backslashes if it is needed)

```
<form name="radioTest"action="radiobuttontest.php" method="post"> ...
```

Comment: well how about fixing the others while your at it ?

Comment: @Dagon they probably ran out of space.

Comment: @Dagon This is a Q&A site, not jibber-jabber playground

Comment: @Dagon it's not as bad as that "other" answer earlier.

Comment: @Dagon Does you definition of "proper" answer include Cold-war time jokes for third-graders?

Comment: @Dagon I do not consider such kind of jokes as a jokes. So, what is the "proper" answer in your opinion anyway?